# Removing Individual Post Pages from Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Currently, when you make a post in Jekyll it auto-creates a permalink for that post, usually `https://website.com/blog/15/01/2020/name_of_post`

However, how would I go about removing these individual pages from Jekyll, so only the main page exists with all of the content and there aren't any permalinks to posts.

Basically, if someone goes to `https://website.com/blog/15/01/2020/name_of_post` it would 404 and they could instead only see that post on `https://website.com/blog/`

I don't want to remove the post themselves, just the individual pages that show only the post.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by moving all the posts to a collection and switching output to false. This is the new line in my _config.yaml

```
collections:
  hidden_posts:
    output: false
```